# Swift - How to stop currently playing audio automatically when another play button in different UITableView cells are pressed?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, avplayer

I am a swift beginner currently working on my first iOS app.

I have a `TableViewController` which has several cells and each cell contains a play button. When a few play buttons are pressed, a few different audios are played at the same time, but I would like to stop a currently playing audio when another playing play button is pressed.

Here are the sample codes I created.

Please give me an advice. Thank you so much!

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 88
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    return cell
}


}
```

**TableViewCell.swift**

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {

var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
var counter = 0

@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    // Audio player setting
    do {

        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sample", ofType: "mp3")!))
        audioPlayer.delegate = self
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()

    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

    if counter == 0 {
        audioPlayer.play()
        counter = 1
    } else {
        audioPlayer.stop()
        counter = 0
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to create _currentActivePlayer object variable. When you start playing audio then assign to it playing player. When other cell wants to play audio then check that variable, stop the player and assign new playing player.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I tried to create an object like you suggested in ViewController.swift but I'm having a problem of detecting which play button is pressed in table view cell. I am not sure if I am on the right path. Could you please give me more clue? Thank you in advance.

Comment: There are many questions on Stackoverflow how to get corresponding cell in a button handler. I don't want to duplicate answers, just find the solution.